# csv module to write columns starting after the first?

Tags: python, csv

Is it possible to write data column-wise in .csv.
I have a code that write first column bur instead to go in start, it start writing second column after the first;like

```
run1
run2
run3 
    2 
    4
    5
```

I want to write second column adjacent to the first:

```
run1 2
run2 4
run3 5
```

following is the the write code:

```
for filename in files:
 out.write(os.path.basename(filename))
 #out.write('\n')
 out.write('\t')
 for line in open(filename,'r'):

    c.update(line.split())

 for item in c.items():
  oi=("{}\t{}".format(*item))  
  out_array = oi.split()

  if out_array[0]=='00000000':

   out.write(out_array[1])
   out.write('\n')
  c.clear()

out.close()
```

Comment: Why not just use csv writer?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. I want aftet first column goes back to start

Comment: I think the indentation in your sample code is messed up and that the code is not complete. Also you don't show your inputs...

Comment: If for some reason you aren't able to generate a row at a time and are forced to work column wise, you could write all the columns as rows and then reopen the file, transpose the data and rewrite it. Although you could also just dump the data into a nested list and then transpose it before using `csv.writer.writerows`.